# SSIS .net url encoding

Tags: c#, ssis, httpclient, .net-4.5, dotnet-httpclient

I need some help with URL encoding in SSIS script task.

Problem:

URL encoding is not working when I call a .net dll (that has the encoding logic) from SSIS script task. But works as expected when I call the same dll from a .net console project.

Description:

I have built a .net function that is part of a dll I reference in SSIS script task.

This .net function takes in a string value as parameter and builds a uri. I url encode the parameter value since it has special characters, in this case it is a  / (forward slash).

When I reference this function in a .net console application the url encoding works as expected. But when I reference this same module in SSIS script task, the / does not get encoded. The target framework is 4.5 (both in .net dll and SSIS script task)

Http Request Generated from below code:

URl Request from SSIS Script task:

GET https://api-servername.net/client/office/Raleigh+Addr%3a+AFO-613/618/custom-data

URl Request from .Net Console application (correct one):

GET https://api-servername.net/client/office/Raleigh+Addr%3a+AFO-613%2f618/custom-data

.Net DLL Code that is referenced :

```
public void GetLCDClientOffice(string officename) 
{
    using (var client = BuildClient())
   {
       var url = String.Format("{0}/{1}/{2}"
                  , this.ResourceName 
                  , this.OFFICE_PATH 
                  , Uri.EscapeDataString(officename));          

      var uri = new Uri(ServiceUri, url);   

      string url1 = ServiceUri.ToString() + 
                    String.Format("{0}/{1}/{2}",this.ResourceName
                                  , OFFICE_PATH,  System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(officename));

        // Get Async unescapes %2F back to / when called from from SSIS script task but works from .net console project
        var response = await client.GetAsync(uri); 
        var response = await client.GetAsync(url1); // same behavior

        // do something with response
   }
}
public HttpClient BuildClient()
{
     var client = new HttpClient();
     client.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 30, 0);

    return client;
}
```

Comment: Have you code stepped it, so you can be certain that it's GetAsync() method that's unescaping it?

Comment: When it goes wrong, are you running the SSIS package in SSDT or on a server?

Comment: .NET Framework 4.5 is deprecated -- see .NET Blog > Support Ending for the .NET Framework 4, 4.5 and 4.5.1 : https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2015/12/09/support-ending-for-the-net-framework-4-4-5-and-4-5-1/

Comment: HttpClient is distributed by nuget -- Microsoft .NET Framework 4 HTTP Client Libraries: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Http/2.0.20710 . Plenty of scope to get different versions linking in, I would have thought.

Comment: Appreciate the response Richard. To answer your question:

Yes, I did code stepped and captured the traffic using fiddler. The GetAsync() method unescapes the %2F to /

It went wrong in our prod server and then we started to debug in SSDT, which behaves the same.

Yes, HttpClient is from Nuget.

Comment: I'm sorry, not sure if I follow you. I'm using latest Nuget libraries that support .net framework 4.5.
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Http/2.2.29
What do you mean by differnt version linking in?

Comment: Fyi, I repointed to .Net 4.6 (dll and script task) but still the same behavior.

Comment: I was thinking that if there's a difference in behaviour in the HttpClient, then maybe different versions are being used.

Comment: You've loaded your DLL into the GAC, so it can be referenced by the Script Task?

Comment: Yes loaded DLL into GAC else script task would not even find it.

Comment: I can reproduce the error, not that that helps very much. I'm using a simplified URL ending in "api/test/Raleigh%2FAddr". When I run it from a C# console app the request stays encoded in Fiddler. When I run it from an SSIS Script Task in SSDT it changes to "api/test/Raleigh/Addr". I haven't tested it on a server.

Comment: I'm using Process Explorer to see what DLLs are being loaded. See TechNet > Process Explorer: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx . My DLL is being loaded from GAC in both cases (console app and SSIS Script Task). The same version of System.Net.Http.ni.dll is being loaded. So no obvious difference.

Comment: Similar problem in this post, but no answer. MSDN Forums > Encoding a Forward Slash in a URL: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0bbc14eb-d3f4-46c9-91d4-0ffd9f9766e8/encoding-a-forward-slash-in-a-url?forum=ncl

Comment: Hi Richard, FYI...I built a .net console application and transferred the SSIS script task logic in there. In SSIS I use Execute Process Task to call that console application. It works..

Comment: That's interesting! There's something strange going on here...

Comment: What is the error you are getting @San?